# What is the better way to format the data before display to the View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

For example, I would like to change my ID to a custom code (12 -> A00012). Where should my function put in this conversion? In my previous coding, I did put in the View form, however, I think I should put in Model. How is the implementation in MVC ASP.NET?

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.  Provide some code so we can see what you are currently doing, and what you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, formatting should be in the view since things like appropriate currency/date formats are part of the user experience. Basically, you don't want to force an American date format on a European user and vice versa. Nor do you want to send a user's culture info down to your model. Usually things like padding should go at the user level as well.

In other cases, perhaps such as your special code, you may want to look into [Attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0w1kczw.aspx). For example, one place I used them was on a legacy data column that was a string that would either represent a date or some pre-defined statuses (like HOLD). By using an Attribute, I was able to essentially strongly type this column rather than allowing it to be a free-from string.